# Installation loop: "The specified service already exists" and "The specified service does not exist as an installed service"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-service

When installing an in-house developed service on a Windows Server 2012 R2, the system has somehow come into a state where InstallUtil.exe thinks a service both exists and does not exist. Upon installation command, the process starts and rolls back with the error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service already exists

Upon giving InstallUtil.exe an uninstall command for that very service file, the process ultimately completes with the error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service does not exist as an installed service

The service did in fact exist prior to my attempt to uninstall and reinstall, though I can find no traces of it now in the Powershell command Get-Service, nor assembly files, nor in the registry. I believe this was triggered by the service name changing in the compiled software without a complete uninstall/reinstall (as in, simply overwriting the executable). My question is, what can I do now to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Have you rebooted the server?  Does the same version of the software install properly on a test machine?  Have you tried using Process Monitor to diagnose the issue?

Comment: This is the test machine; the issue also exists in production. Reboots happen infrequently; I made that request of server support today. I haven't used ProcMon yet to diagnose, but it looks promising, so that's my next step.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a clean test machine - one on which the software has never previously been installed.  Doesn't need to be a real machine, of course, could just be a disposal VM.  The point is to determine whether it's the state of the machine that's the problem, e.g., something related to the change you mention, or just something broken in the installer package.

Comment: Updates: on a clean test machine (a VM), the service installs and uninstalls as expected. Also, a reboot of the server in question does not alter the above state, and the loop persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was found and determined to be: another developer had inadvertently added a second service installer with the exact same service name in the project. (He had not tested this change, of course.) The net result of attempting to install two services with the exact same name was not reflected in any of the Windows or installation logs, nor in the command prompt when the service was installed via command line.

To make this diagnosis, I had gone into the source code and altered the service name myself. When rebuilt and installed, two services had been added to the Services list.

Comment: Reminds me of what one of my IT instructors once said: "Computers are stupid, but stupid fast." (They will do whatever you tell them to do and do it fast, even if it's something they shouldn't do.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that the somewhat generic name of "Monitor" I had chosen actually did already exist.  I came up with a more specific name and everything worked.